# Vb.net TcpClient Error

Tags: sockets, tcpclient, whois

I'm trying to get whois information in vb.net

I found a code

```
Private Function whoiscek(ByVal whoisServer As String, ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim stringBuilderResult As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim tcpClinetWhois As TcpClient = New TcpClient(whoisServer, 43)
    Dim networkStreamWhois As NetworkStream = tcpClinetWhois.GetStream()
    Dim bufferedStreamWhois As BufferedStream = New BufferedStream(networkStreamWhois)
    Dim streamWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(bufferedStreamWhois)

    streamWriter.WriteLine(url)
    streamWriter.Flush()

    Dim streamReaderReceive As StreamReader = New StreamReader(bufferedStreamWhois)

    While Not streamReaderReceive.EndOfStream
        stringBuilderResult.AppendLine(streamReaderReceive.ReadLine())
    End While

    Return stringBuilderResult.ToString()
End Function
```

But I got an error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwkJh.png)

[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

How To Fix Error ?

Comment: Ensure :43 is open on any Windows/physical firewalls.

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Comment: Which whois server you are querying?